# Bash: Date-epoch with systemd

Tags: linux, bash, systemd

I execute the following line in a bash console.

```
/bin/bash -c "echo `date` random=$((RANDOM % 10)) > /tmp/my.log"
```

The content of my.log is as expected.

```
Mo Aug 24 14:37:04 CEST 2020 random=6
```

Now I change the timestamp to epoch (format-code +%s).

```
/bin/bash -c "echo `date +%s` random=$((RANDOM % 10)) > /tmp/my.log"
```

File is

```
1598272710 random=3
```

As expected again.

But if I put this command line into systemd it would fail.

```
[Service]                                                                                                             
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "echo `date +%s` random=$((RANDOM % 10)) > /tmp/my.log"
```

produces

```
/bin/sh random=7
```

Must be a problem with the format-code of date. If I remove the +%s then it is as expected (normal date-format and no epoch) with systemd too.

Any suggestions what is wrong with my command? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%`-secuences are replaced by systemd. From [systemd.unit manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#):

> Specifiers

> "%s"  User shell  This is the shell of the user running the service manager instance. In case of the system manager this resolves to "/bin/sh".

`%s` is substituted for `/bin/sh`, and `date +/bin/sh` returns `/bin/sh`.

Do:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "echo $(date +%%s) random=$((RANDOM %% 10)) > /tmp/my.log"
```

Using backticks ` is discouraged. Use `$(...)` instead. [bash hackers wiki deprecated and obsolete syntax](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete)

Comment: After ton of time fiddling around google and questioning chatGPT, i stumbled to this answer. This really saved the day. SystemD's issue with %s was not clear until i saw this